# How do I convert a Word Table into an embedded Excel Worksheet?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, vsto, excel-2010, word-2010

I have a document that has multiple Word Tables.  I need to convert them into embedded Excel Worksheets (or COM Objects).  I've been able to "import" the Word Tables into Excel using the following:

```
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        // Call the conversion tool
        for (int i = 1; i <= curDoc.Tables.Count; i++ )
        {
            Word.Table tbl = curDoc.Tables[i];
            Word.Range tblLoc = tbl.Range;



            // Used for debugging.
            xlApp.Visible = true;

            if (xlApp == null)
            {
                messageAlert = "Excel could not be started.  Check that your office installation and project references are correct.";
                break;
            }

            Excel.Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
            Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];


            if (ws == null)
            {
                messageAlert = "Worksheet could not be created.  Check that your office installation and project reference are correct.";
                break;
            }

            Word.Range rng = tbl.ConvertToText(Separator: ";", NestedTables: false);

            string sData = rng.Text;



            string[] rows = sData.Split('\r');

            int r = 1, c = 1;
            int numRows = rows.Count();
            int numCols = rows[0].Split(';').Count();


            foreach (string row in rows)
            {
                string[] cells = row.Split(';');
                foreach (string cell in cells)
                {
                    ws.Cells[r, c].Value = cell;
                    c += 1;
                }
                r += 1;
                c = 1;
            }
```

Problem is whenever I copy the contents back into the document, a new Word Table is created instead of an Excel Worksheet.  How do I either import an Excel Worksheet into Word, or directly convert the tables into Excel Worksheets?

Comment: Are you asking how to paste the Excel layout (the cells) into Word?

Comment: @varocarbas [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mK973.png) is what I'm looking to do.

Comment: I don't think that you can get this with Interop. You have the option to embed Excel/Word "windows" into an application (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/242243/en-us) but doing it in a Word document is over-complicating things. Not sure if it is possible at all/its reliability. Perhaps you should consider other alternative (e.g., open Excel in a small popup).

Comment: @varocarbas I'm assuming if I can do it manually (through importing an "object"), that I *should* be able to do it via interop.

Comment: You can try anything and see the result... perhaps it works :) But "Object" is a neutral type, assumed to be one of the types supported in the given context. If you deal with Excel, the Word objects are not supported (within the Excel object)  and vice versa. Bear in mind what you want to do: not just copying values (the values are recognised by both Excel and Word), but setting up a complex framework (Excel). In case of being possible to do such a thing, you would have to rely on a specific API/Namespace...

Comment: @varocarbas I need to do this, in order to import the tables correctly into DOORS.

Comment: DOORS? As proposed, you can rely on Excel but on a popup or something like that (it would be much easier and doable for sure). In any case, I don't see why you have to copy the whole Excel into Word; in any scenario, I can come up with alternatives. If you want to do it anyway: good luck; but I cannot be of further help.

Comment: @varocarbas I was finally able to figure it out (See answer below).

Comment: Ah an OLE object. With Object, I understood an Object-type. The OLE objects are common to both Excel and Word. I will do a couple of quick tests and if it is reliable enough, I will upvote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, you'll have to first save the excel worksheet and then import it as an `OLEObject`.  Here's an example:

```
public void ConvertTables()
{
    string messageAlert = "";
    Word.Application curApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;

    Word.Document curDoc = curApp.ActiveDocument;
    if (curDoc.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();

        //Used for debugging.
        //xlApp.Visible = true;

        //Call the conversion tool
        for (int i = 1; i <= curDoc.Tables.Count; i++ )
        {
            Word.Table tbl = curDoc.Tables[i];
            Word.Range tblLoc = tbl.Range;

            if (xlApp == null)
            {
                messageAlert = "Excel could not be started.  Check that your office installation and project references are correct.";
                break;
            }

            Excel.Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
            Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];


            if (ws == null)
            {
                messageAlert = "Worksheet could not be created.  Check that your office installation and project reference are correct.";
                break;
            }

            Word.Range rng = tbl.ConvertToText(Separator: ";", NestedTables: false);

            string sData = rng.Text;



            string[] rows = sData.Split('\r');

            int r = 1, c = 1;
            int numRows = rows.Count();
            int numCols = rows[0].Split(';').Count();


            foreach (string row in rows)
            {
                string[] cells = row.Split(';');
                foreach (string cell in cells)
                {
                    ws.Cells[r, c].Value = cell;
                    c += 1;
                }
                r += 1;
                c = 1;
            }

            ws.SaveAs("C:\\temp\\test.xlsx");
            rng.Text = "";
            rng.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(ClassType: "Excel.Sheet.12", FileName: "C:\\temp\\test.xlsx");


            ws.Range["A1", ws.Cells[numRows, numCols]].Value = "";
            ws.SaveAs("C:\\Temp\\test.xlsx");
        }
        xlApp.Quit();

        messageAlert = "Tables converted";
    }
    else
    {
        // No tables found
        messageAlert = "No tables found within the document";
    }


    MessageBox.Show(messageAlert);

}
```

Comment: I see that you are using a Word add-in. I replaced this part with a whole Word document (it shouldn't matter). In my first tests the results were horrible because I tried a blank table (appears a rectangle with nothing on it, getting crazy when you click on it). By putting values, it does not look too bad at a first sight. The resizing part is a bit crappy (but well..). I personally wouldn't use it and another approach (embedding as proposed) might deliver a better solution (although not sure). In any case this is clearly a right answer for your (own) question, +1 :)

Comment: @varocarbas thank you.  I know that the requirements for this are a bit odd, however they are requirements ;)